# CricularProgress Bar is not changing the state from isLoading variable

Tags: flutter, mvvm, flutter-provider

I have Page called ProductSearch and ProductGride if I navigate from search page to gride page isLoading is not updating from the future function of the viewmodel of grid page.

ProductGridePage

```
class ProductGridePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductGridePageState createState()=> _ProductGridePageState();
}


class _ProductGridePageState extends State<ProductGridePage>{
  int page_no=1;
  int page_size=20;
  bool isLoading=true;

  void fetchData() async {
    Provider.of<ProductgridVM>(context,listen: false).fetchProductGridList(
        productcode: productcode,
        branchname: branchname,
        metalname: metalname,
        purityname: purityname,
        seriesname: seriesname,
        producttypename: producttypename,
        collectionname: collectionname,
        categoriesname: categoriesname,
        makingProcessname: makingProcessname,
        page_no: page_no, page_size: page_size).then((value) => isLoading=false);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TextEditingController(text: '1');
    fetchData();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(isLoading);
    return isLoading?Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
         ]
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: From the code I see is  you have a view model in which you might be using the change notifier, in which we will use the notififyListner to change  the state.
But as you have defined the isLoading in the UI Page it will not reload unless you add that in the view model and then change the state over there.

Answer (score 0):

Put isLoading = false into the setState method after then or else you can call that in `.whenComplete`

```
void fetchData() async {
    Provider.of<ProductgridVM>(context,listen: false).fetchProductGridList(
        productcode: productcode,
        branchname: branchname,
        metalname: metalname,
        purityname: purityname,
        seriesname: seriesname,
        producttypename: producttypename,
        collectionname: collectionname,
        categoriesname: categoriesname,
        makingProcessname: makingProcessname,
        page_no: page_no, page_size: page_size).then((value) => setState((){
isLoading=false;})}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isLoading` state is not changing. You need to change the state of it.
Try as follows

```
void fetchData() async {
Provider.of<ProductgridVM>(context,listen: false).fetchProductGridList(
    productcode: productcode,
    branchname: branchname,
    metalname: metalname,
    purityname: purityname,
    seriesname: seriesname,
    producttypename: producttypename,
    collectionname: collectionname,
    categoriesname: categoriesname,
    makingProcessname: makingProcessname,
    page_no: page_no, page_size: page_size).then((value) {
    /// You need to change the state like this

    setState((){
isLoading=false});
}
    );
     }
```

Comment: if i use this I have list of model that is still empty

Comment: List<ProductGridModel> productGridlist =
        Provider.of<ProductgridVM>(context,listen: false).getProductGridList();

Comment: are you getting data after empty error message?

Comment: for the first time it is empty if i navigate to other page and back to this page its not empty

Comment: Are you getting value in the console? try printing the value of .then(value)

Comment: No for the first time in console also empty later it will change

Comment: Do you get the value after some time of the error message without navigating?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setstate()` to update the state. After navigating to the other page setstate() will help you to react accordingly.

Wrap isLoading with `setstate()`